# Access to media files only for authenticated users

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have project in django 1.0.4 - yes I know it is old.

I want to use the lack of access to media (audio) files for users who are not logged in.
After making changes to nginx, logged in users also have no access.

I tried with view and url function - no result

my nginx settings:

```
location /media/content/audio/ {
    deny all;
}
```

my function and url

```
    @login_required
    def protected_serve(request, path, document_root=None, show_indexes=False):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            raise Http404()
        else:
            return serve(request, path, document_root, show_indexes)

    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/content/audio/(?P<path>.*)$', protected_serve),
    )
```

Comment: Until Django 1.10, you need to call the `is_authenticated` method, i.e. `request.user.is_authenticated()`. However that won't fix the access for logged-in users.

Comment: @Alasdair it is, please check my code.

Comment: I don't think you understood my first comment. You have `request.user.is_authenticated`, you are missing the `()`.

Comment: @Alasdair, sorry, you are right. But the same behavior

Comment: Yes, as I said, that won't fix the access for logged-in users ;)

Comment: I don't think it's going to work with `deny all;` for `location /media/content/audio/` - you need to pass those requests to Django. I'm afraid I don't have any specific solution for you.

Comment: A quick google search yielded these two articles ([github.io](https://b0uh.github.io/protect-django-media-files-per-user-basis-with-nginx.html) and [wellfire.co](https://wellfire.co/learn/nginx-django-x-accel-redirects/)) on how to use nginx `X-Accel-Redirect`. Maybe that helps you.

Comment: @Ralf your content bring me closer to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close to having the whole puzzle put together.  There are two things you need to do:

1. Configure NGINX that you do want to be able to serve data from a particular folder, but that said folder isn't public.  The authorization to send files from a folder will come from the application behind NGINX, not from external requests to NGINX.
2. Have your django app send the kind of response to NGINX that NGINX understands to mean "serve this file from the protected area in 1"

The way you achieve the first goal is to use the config directive "internal"

Achieving the second goal is to use the HTTP response header "X-Accel-Redirect" as @ralf states in the comments above.

Here is a blog post on the subject: https://clubhouse.io/developer-how-to/how-to-use-internal-redirects-in-nginx/

A Python project to help you achieve the same goal: https://pypi.org/project/django-transfer/

NGINX Docs: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/xsendfile/